# RichTextBox maximum size limitation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I use RichTextBox to display a content. But it displays only the beginning of it, nearly 2000 px. and then there is an empty field. Is it possible to show all content?

**Update**

Adding a ScrollViewer doesn't help

```
 <Grid Visibility="{Binding ItemVisibility}" Margin="0,-25,0,0"  Width="480" Background="#dcdcdc">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" MinHeight="730">
                                                              <RichTextBox x:Name="Browser" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" Logic:RichTextBoxHelper.Html="{Binding BrowserHtml}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Width="430" Margin="0,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

The maximum display size of any control in WP7 is 2048 x 2048 px, so if you are at that limit you will experience issues like this.

Comment: Have a look at this question for some good suggestions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573038/wp7-scrollviewer-bug-when-content-height-2000px

Answer (score 0):

The 2048x2048 limit is for any single element. The way to get around this restriction is to split your data into chunks, each chunk being inside a new element (i.e. TextBlock).  There are several example snippets available if you search google.

Take a look at this [Scrollable-TextBlock solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)